# cin.getline isn't working properly

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

I'm writing a small shell program, but I can't even get past reading a line of input. I'm using cin.getline() to read the user supplied args into a text buffer but it doesn't work. Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char buffer[1024];
   cout << "John's Shell>>";
   cin.ignore(17);
   cin.getline(buffer, 1024);
   cout << buffer << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to use cin.ignore(); to ignore my prompt as well as the newline character. All that happens is that after I press enter I just get a blank output. buffer is never printed. I appreciate any help

Comment: To ignore any *whitespaces* (`\n` is a whitespace), you can use [`cin >> ws;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws). To ignore *any character* until a `\n`, you can use `cin.ignore(x, '\n');`, where `x` can be a number or `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`.

Comment: BTW, it's easier to use `std::getline()` from `<string>` instead, and then you won't need to deal with fixed-size buffers.

Comment: Consider using `std::string` for `buffer`, and then using `std::getline(std::cin, buffer)` to read data into `buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to use cin.ignore(); to ignore my prompt

Then don't. You don't need to. The input you take from `cin`'s buffer is separated from whatever device `cout` stream is sending characters to.

`cin.ignore(17)` just waits until there are 17 characters to ignore, so `cin.getline(buffer, 1024)` will only be able to read those that are left (if any).

You'd use this function to ignore undesired characters that are waiting in the input buffer, for example when you encounter that parsing failed:

```
int i;
if (cin >> i) {
    cout << "You entered: " << i << '\n';
} else {
    // input not an integer, get rid of it:
    cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

And there's an easier an more robust way to take a line of input:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

No off-by-one errors and no buffer overflows. `std::string` will grow automatically to accomodate any size of input, up to avaliable memory.

Comment: That makes sense but for example if I enter "hello" after the prompt then hit enter, literally all that happens is that I get a newline. buffer isn't printed to the screen

Comment: @JohnDodson Works for me. Did you remove `cin.ignore(17);` line?